# How to remove an array elemet from a certain prosition in solidity?

Tags: arrays, ethereum, solidity

Is there any method in solidity like array.remove or somthing to delete an element from a certain position where it won't leave a gap.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to delete item of array in solidity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71268574/how-to-delete-item-of-array-in-solidity)

Answer (score 0):

Not without leaving a gap.

To delete an item from an array, you'll need to move all following items to the left, and remove the last item.

```
pragma solidity ^0.8;

contract MyContract {
    uint256[] array = [100, 200, 300, 400, 500];

    function remove(uint256 index) external {
        require(array.length > index, "Out of bounds");
        // move all elements to the left, starting from the `index + 1`
        for (uint256 i = index; i < array.length - 1; i++) {
            array[i] = array[i+1];
        }
        array.pop(); // delete the last item
    }

    function getArray() external view returns (uint256[] memory) {
        return array;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any method which delete an element & move all item automatically or I have to manually do it all time

Comment: @BappiRahman No native method (v0.8.11).