# How to store unique value in an array using for loop in Solidity?

Tags: solidity

I want to store unique addresses in the array and then increment the count. But I am not able to do it. The count variable is not incremented and returns 0. Also redundant addresses are stored in the array.

Can you please help?

```
function placeBid() public payable notOwner afterStart beforeEnd returns(bool){
               
                require(auctionState == State.Running);
                uint currentBid = 0;
                if(totalBidder>0)
                {
                   currentBid =  bids[msg.sender] + msg.value;
                   require(currentBid > highestBindingBid);
                   
                }
                else{
      require(msg.value > startBid && msg.value > highestBindingBid);
                      currentBid =  msg.value;
                     
                }
                
          
               bids[msg.sender] = currentBid;
        
               for(uint i=0; i<bidders.length; i++){
                   if(msg.sender!=bidders[i]) 

                   bidders.push(payable(msg.sender));
                   totalBidder++;
                   }
                }
               
                highestBindingBid = currentBid;
                highestBidder = payable(msg.sender);
        
            return true;
            }
```

Comment: How is the `bidders` array defined? And where - inside a function or as a storage property?

Comment: address payable[] public bidders; It is defined as storage property. And I have used for loop inside a function.

Comment: That looks fine regarding the syntax and data location. What exactly is your issue? Are you getting an error message or unexpected runtime results? Please edit your question and provide steps to reproduce the issue.

Comment: I have updated the question. Can you please help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy (and cheaper compared to your snippet) way to push only unique items to a storage array is to duplicate the values in a mapping, and then validate against the mapping.

```
pragma solidity ^0.8;

contract MyContract {
    address payable[] public bidders;
    mapping (address => bool) isBidder; // default `false`

    // only add `msg.sender` to `bidders` if it's not there yet
    function placeBid() public {
        // check against the mapping
        if (isBidder[msg.sender] == false) {
            // push the unique item to the array
            bidders.push(payable(msg.sender));
            // don't forget to set the mapping value as well
            isBidder[msg.sender] = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, It worked!! I am a novice and you provided such an easy and simple solution. I am really grateful. Thank You so much!! 

Comment: so how do you delete a bidder? you don't know it's position in the array. deleting from the map won't do it because the address will be still stored in the array. the entire structure will contain invalid data

Comment: @Nulik It depends on whether you need to keep the order of items or not. If not, you can replace the deleted item by the last item and then `pop()` the last (https://stackoverflow.com/a/71271076/1693192). If you need to keep the order, then you'll have to loop which is expensive gas-wise (https://stackoverflow.com/a/70756474/1693192). You can also use ordered list (https://stackoverflow.com/a/75247596/1693192) or other workarounds instead of an array if it fits your use case better.