# How to optimize this smart contract function in Solidity about deleting an element in particular index of an array

Tags: arrays, algorithm, solidity, smartcontracts

I used the following library code to delete an element in array according to its index.
The only way in my mind is using loop, but it costs a lot of gas.
Is there any other optimized code to solve this problem?

```
library ArrayLibrary {
    function remove(uint[] storage _arr, uint _removedIndex) public returns(uint[] memory){
        require(_arr.length > 0, "No element in Array.");
        for(uint i; i < _arr.length - 1; i++){
            if (i >= _removedIndex) {
                _arr[i] = _arr[i + 1];               
            } 
        }
        _arr.pop();
        return _arr;
    }
}


contract TestLibrary {
    uint[] arr;
    using ArrayLibrary for uint[];

    function deleteArrEle(uint[] calldata _arr, uint deletedIndex) public returns (uint[] memory deletedArr) {
        arr = _arr;
        deletedArr = arr.remove(deletedIndex);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind switching order of the items, you can copy the last item to the position of the unwanted item and then remove the last.

```
function remove(uint[] storage _arr, uint _removedIndex) public returns(uint[] memory){
    require(_arr.length > 0, "No element in Array.");
    _arr[_removedIndex] = _arr[_arr.length-1];
    _arr.pop();
    return _arr;
}
```

Input array `[1,2,3,4]`, removing at index 1 (value 2). Output `[1,4,3]`.

---

There is also a bit more complex workaround with linked sorted list. Example code in Liquity protocol's [SortedTroves](https://etherscan.io/address/0x8FdD3fbFEb32b28fb73555518f8b361bCeA741A6#code) for example.

The sorted data is not stored in an array but in a mapping of structs that point to previous and next items.

- key A:

  - value 1
  - link to previous key: empty (meaning there's no previous value)
  - link to next key: D
- key C:

  - value 7
  - link to previous key: D
  - link to next key: empty (meaning there's no next key)
- key D:

  - value 5
  - link to previous key: A
  - link to next key: C

The contract also holds info about keys of lowest and highest value.

When you're removing an item, you only remove this specific item, and change the 2 links (next and previous) that originally pointed to this item.

Comment: Use the mapping is a good idea, but I think items in mapping is also with no order, isn't it? Let me check your recommended contract first, thanks a lot.

Comment: @Huowuge Simple mapping is not ordered, the linked contract uses mapping of structs - each of the structs contains link to previous and next item in the sorted list.